# VBA Chart is not pasting as PNG

Tags: excel, vba

So I made a macro to copy and paste (line graph) from one sheet to another as a PNG file. But when i run the code the graph does not appear. Please advise

The variable "p" is just a counter, for pasting other graphs when the data is refreshed after a loop.

```
Worksheets("Data").Activate
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Graph1").Activate
    ActiveChart.ChartArea.Copy

    Sheets("List").Select
    Range("A" & p).Select

   ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Format:="Picture (PNG)", Link:=False, _
        DisplayAsIcon:=False
p=p+46
```

I tried this and it still didnt work

```
 Worksheets("Data").Activate
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Graph1").Activate
    ActiveChart.ChartArea.CopyPicture Format:=xlPicture

    Sheets("List").Select
    Range("A" & p).Select

   ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial

p = p + 46
```

@Nanashi Just tried this and it didnt work unfortunately

```
 Worksheets("Data").Activate
        Dim WS As Worksheet: Set WS = ActiveSheet
    Dim Cht As Chart
    Set Cht = WS.ChartObjects("StockGraph").Chart
    Cht.ChartArea.Copy



    Sheets("List").Select
    Range("A" & p).Select

 WS.Pictures.Paste
```

Here is the code as requested: (Thank you for your help!)

```
Sub Execute()
Dim mark As String

Worksheets("Tab").Activate
Range("I3").Select
lr = Selection.End(xlDown).row

pst = 5
pstc = 12
pstg = 6
oro = 1
opo = 3
l = 25
m = 32
n = 39
o = 5
p = 11
pstc = 21

For s = 5 To lr

On Error Resume Next

Worksheets("Tab").Activate

mark= Cells(s, 9)
Cells(6, 2) = mark

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

Call Macro2
Call Macro1

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

'==================================================================='

Range("I1:L5").Copy
Worksheets("List").Activate
Range("H" & o).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

'''graph'''''''''
        Worksheets("Data").Activate
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Graph1").Activate
    ActiveChart.ChartArea.Copy

    Sheets("List").Select
    Range("A" & p).Select

   ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Format:="Picture (PNG)", Link:=False, _
        DisplayAsIcon:=False

p = p + 46

    Worksheets("Data").Activate
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Graph1").Delete
```

Comment: try ActiveChart.ChartArea.CopyPicture format:=xlPicture

Comment: Didnt seem to work :/ (see edit)

Comment: What do you get? do you get an error?

Comment: nope, the code just keeps running without pasting the chart

Comment: Kindly post a one-line reply to the answer as well. Tagging on the OP will not notify us. Anyway, I'm guessing that the loop is badly constructed. `Select` is also a general no-no 99% of the time. Would you mind posting the entire code please?

Comment: Just posted it, thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Use the `Worksheet` property/method `.Pictures.Paste`. See code below.

```
Sub Test()

    Dim WS As Worksheet: Set WS = ActiveSheet
    Dim Cht As Chart
    Set Cht = WS.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart
    Cht.ChartArea.Copy
    WS.Range("R1").Select
    WS.Pictures.Paste

End Sub
```

This pastes `Chart 1` to the `R1` cell as a picture.

Let us know if this helps.

Answer (score -1):

This is all you need to copy the chart and paste a picture of it:

```
Sub CopyPasteChartPicture()
  ActiveChart.CopyPicture xlScreen, xlPicture
  ActiveSheet.Range("E5").Select ' or wherever...
  ActiveSheet.Paste
End Sub
```